# Style links inside blockquote list

Tags: css

- inside a div, I have a `<blockquote>`
- inside that `<blockquote>`, I have a list
- and in that list a link is featured, like:

> ```
> <div class="article">
>   <BLOCKQUOTE><B class="big">big bold heading</B>
>   <ul>
>       <li><A HREF="link" target="_blank">title 1</A></li>
>       <li><A HREF="link" target="_blank">title 2</A></li>
>       etc.
>   </ul>
>   </BLOCKQUOTE>
> </div>
> ```

Feel like a fool asking this, but why doesn't this (and everything else I've tried) work in my css?

> `.article blockquote ul li a {
>   font-size: 20pt;
>   }`

Comment: Works for me in latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Well, not here! haha!

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? Is your CSS being compiled and loaded properly?

Comment: Everything looks good here, also in the console. That's why I am asking here. Haven't got a clue why this is not working.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome, latest version

Comment: There is nothing in the entire css that interferes with it even. Is there like a go-around for it, maybe?

Comment: sorry for this one, I forgot the main pre-defined selector. Should I delete this one to keep the database clean? Should be best, I think. Can any moderator advice me here?

Comment: Works perfectly in chrome.

Comment: Thanks @Sushil, we've already figured it all out with the help of the moderators here.